# npm install error CLI

Tags: node.js, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to install CLI. I'm getting the following error
Can you guys tell me how to solve that. Tks!

```
Tungs-MacBook-Pro:~ tungvu$ npm install -g --no-optional path_cli_file
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "--no-optional" "path_cli_file"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/path_cli_file
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'path_cli_file' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/tungvu/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to install?  The error is telling you that the `path_cli_file` doesn't exist on https://www.npmjs.com  you may also want to read over https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: I'm trying to install mfpdev-cli.tgz

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [mfpdev-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mfpdev-cli) you should run

`npm install -g --no-optional mfpdev-cli`

or if you've downloaded the tar file locally you could run

`npm install -g --no-optional /path/to/mfpdev-cli.tgz`